# Javascript if statement not triggering 'true' statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a multi-step form that relies on javascript to determine the options show in step 2.

The if statement should take the value of the email field and should show a specific option (div element) if the domain is @vip.co.uk and a set of general options (div element) if any other domain is used.

The form is working as it should but I seem to be seeing the general options for all email domains, the if statement doesn't appear to be working.

Below is the If statement:

```
function checkEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var idx = email.lastIndexOf('@');
    if (idx > -1 && email.slice(idx + 1) === 'vip.co.uk'){
        document.getElementById('special').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('general').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", checkEmail);
```

Given the amount of code I have created a JS fiddle with the full form at http://jsfiddle.net/zsasvoo4/.

I'm keen to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: there is no element with id `next` - see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null `

Comment: there is an error in the javascript and its shown in console..

Comment: your `next` button has `name="next"`, not id is present

Comment: Thanks - that has done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Open debug console and you will see that `document.getElementById("next")` returns undefined. There is no element with ID `next`. You could solve this by adding `id="next"` to the button.
2. If you are using jQuery it is more common to use `$('#next')` instead of `.getElementById()` methods. And, if you are using jQuery you could also select the button with `$('[name=next]')` if you don't want to change the markup. The full code to attach the event handler could be written as: `$('[name=next]').click(checkEmail);`